# Navigator drawer header image does not set in Firebase query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Navigator drawer header picture does not set in my Firebase query. It does not give an error but it does not show the load picture.

Kotlin;

```
val navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView
        val headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
        var imageViewUser = headerview.imgUserProfilNav as ImageView
        mUserAuthListener = object : FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
            override fun onAuthStateChanged(p0: FirebaseAuth) {
                var kullanici = p0.currentUser
               //  Glide.with(this@ProfilNavMenu).load(R.drawable.ic_action_user).into(imageViewUser)
                headerview.imgUserProfilNav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_user)
                if (kullanici != null) {
                   // Picasso.with(this@ProfilNavMenu).load(R.drawable.ic_action_user).fit().centerCrop().into(headerview.imgUserProfilNav)

                }
            }
        }
```

ProfileNavMenu - nav_header_profil_nav_menu.xml ;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgUserProfilNav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I set the picture with Kotlin and Firebase? I have even tried with `Glide` but still it didn't show any picture of url or drawable pictures.

Comment: attach your xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
mUserAuthListener = object : FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
            override fun onAuthStateChanged(p0: FirebaseAuth) {
                var kullanici = p0.currentUser
               //  Glide.with(this@ProfilNavMenu).load(R.drawable.ic_action_user).into(imageViewUser)
                headerview.imgUserProfilNav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_user)
                if (kullanici != null) {
                   // Picasso.with(this@ProfilNavMenu).load(R.drawable.ic_action_user).fit().centerCrop().into(headerview.imgUserProfilNav)

                }
            }
        }
```

Try this:

```
 mUserAuthListener = object : FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
            override fun onAuthStateChanged(p0: FirebaseAuth) {

           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Set Image here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

This will help you if your `onAuthStatChanged` is running each time or not. If it's not running each time you will have to usdifferentce approach.

Finally the running code will be:

```
val navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView
        val headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
        var imageViewUser = headerview.imgUserProfilNav as ImageView
              headerview.imgUserProfilNav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_user)
        mUserAuthListener = object : FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
            override fun onAuthStateChanged(p0: FirebaseAuth) {
                var kullanici = p0.currentUser

                if (kullanici != null) {
                    //set image if there is any specific requirement
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you mean you didn't get any toast?

Comment: this means your image should not set also. Please move                 headerview.imgUserProfilNav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_user)
 this line outside of onAuthStateChanged.

Comment: yes you are right, the toast message does not show anything.. how i can get the activity?

Comment: the toast will only show up when onAuthStateChange() calls otherwise it'll not run any code inside this method.

Comment: yes bro u're right, its my bad. i put wrong query, thank u a lot. u saved my time :)